# How to not close a xtk:SplitButton's custom Popup when a click is made on a button inside it?

Tags: c#, wpf, apply-templates, wpf-extended-toolkit

I have a custom control with an override for OnApplyTemplate. In it I tried to access children of children templates but they seem to not be loaded. What I wish: when the `PART_IncreaseButton` inside the `Popup` of a `xtk:SplitButton` is clicked, the `Popup` will not close but just let the `Button` react to the click.

`CustomIntegerUpDown` and `CustomSplitButton` are derived from the Xceed Extended WPF Toolkit. CustomIntegerUpDown has no changed style or template or code-behind and currently its only purpose is to do what I said above but I am just at the beginning of it. Below is all the relevant source.

I tried this:

```
IncrementButton = Utils.FindChild<RepeatButton>(PartPopup, "PART_IncreaseButton")
```

and IncrementButton is null after that, although in the Immediate Window:

`Utils.FindChild<Popup>(this, "PART_Popup")` returns the `Popup` as obtained from `GetTemplateChild("PART_Popup")`.

then

`Utils.FindChild<ButtonSpinner>(PartPopup, "PART_Spinner")` returns `null`.

`Utils.FindChild<CustomIntegerUpDown>(PartPopup, "MyCustomIntegerUpDown")` return `null`.

`VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(PartPopup)` returns `0`.

`PartPopup.ApplyTemplate()` returns `false`.

I've also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34505815/258462) and I am not sure if it is worth trying that way.

`FindChild` is this (took from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1759923/258462)):

```cs
/// <summary>
/// Finds a Child of a given item in the visual tree.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="parent">A direct parent of the queried item.</param>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the queried item.</typeparam>
/// <param name="childName">x:Name or Name of child. </param>
/// <returns>The first parent item that matches the submitted type parameter.
/// If not matching item can be found,
/// a null parent is being returned.</returns>
public static T FindChild<T>(System.Windows.DependencyObject parent, string childName)
    where T : System.Windows.DependencyObject
{
    // Confirm parent and childName are valid.
    if (parent == null) return null;
    T foundChild = null;
    int childrenCount = System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
    {
        var child = System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        // If the child is not of the request child type child
        T childType = child as T;
        if (childType == null)
        {
            // recursively drill down the tree
            foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);
            // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child.
            if (foundChild != null) break;
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
        {
            var frameworkElement = child as System.Windows.FrameworkElement;
            // If the child's name is set for search
            if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
            {
                // if the child's name is of the request name
                foundChild = (T)child;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // child element found.
            foundChild = (T)child;
            break;
        }
    }
    return foundChild;
}
```

In **CustomSplitButton.xaml.cs** I have this:

```cs
internal Popup PartPopup;
internal Button PartButtonWith1, PartButtonWith5, PartButtonWith10, PartButtonWithCustom;
internal RepeatButton IncrementButton;
public override void OnApplyTemplate()
{
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    PartPopup = (Popup)GetTemplateChild("PART_Popup");
    PartButtonWith1 = (Button)GetTemplateChild("PART_ButtonWith1");
    PartButtonWith5 = (Button)GetTemplateChild("PART_ButtonWith5");
    PartButtonWith10 = (Button)GetTemplateChild("PART_ButtonWith10");
    PartButtonWithCustom = (Button)GetTemplateChild("PART_ButtonWithCustom");
    PartPopup.ApplyTemplate();
    IncrementButton = Utils.FindChild<RepeatButton>(PartPopup, "PART_IncreaseButton");
    if (PartPopup != null)
    {
        PartPopup.PreviewMouseDown += PART_Popup_PreviewMouseUp;
        PartPopup.PreviewMouseUp += PART_Popup_PreviewMouseUp;
    }
    if (PartButtonWith1 != null)
    {
        PartButtonWith1.Click += Btns_NewTimer_Click;
    }
    if (PartButtonWith5 != null)
    {
        PartButtonWith5.Click += Btns_NewTimer_Click;
    }
    if (PartButtonWith10 != null)
    {
        PartButtonWith10.Click += Btns_NewTimer_Click;
    }
    if (PartButtonWithCustom != null)
    {
        PartButtonWithCustom.Click += BtnCustom_Click;
    }
}
```

The visual tree is this:

[image: screenshot with the live visual tree]

The style of **CustomSplitButton** is the following (`xmlns:xtkThemes="clr-namespace:Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.Themes;assembly=Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit"`):

```xml
<Style x:Key="AddCountSplitButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type xtk:SplitButton}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=ButtonNormalBackgroundKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type xtkThemes:ResourceKeys}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=ButtonNormalOuterBorderKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type xtkThemes:ResourceKeys}}}"/>
    <Setter Property="DropDownContentBackground">
        <Setter.Value>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F0" Offset="0"/>
                <GradientStop Color="#FFE5E5E5" Offset="1"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type xtk:SplitButton}">
                <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                    <xtk:ButtonChrome x:Name="ControlChrome" BorderThickness="0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" RenderEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Button x:Name="PART_ActionButton" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="0" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Style="{x:Null}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}">
                                <Button.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"/>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Button.Template>
                                <Grid>
                                    <xtk:ButtonChrome x:Name="ActionButtonChrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" RenderMouseOver="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_ActionButton}" RenderPressed="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=PART_ActionButton}" RenderEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled}">
                                        <xtk:ButtonChrome.BorderThickness>
                                            <Binding ConverterParameter="2" Path="BorderThickness" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}">
                                                <Binding.Converter>
                                                    <xtk:ThicknessSideRemovalConverter/>
                                                </Binding.Converter>
                                            </Binding>
                                        </xtk:ButtonChrome.BorderThickness>
                                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ActionButtonContent" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                                    </xtk:ButtonChrome>
                                </Grid>
                            </Button>
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="PART_ToggleButton" Grid.Column="1" IsChecked="{Binding IsOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                <ToggleButton.IsHitTestVisible>
                                    <Binding Path="IsOpen" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}">
                                        <Binding.Converter>
                                            <xtk:InverseBoolConverter/>
                                        </Binding.Converter>
                                    </Binding>
                                </ToggleButton.IsHitTestVisible>
                                <ToggleButton.Template>
                                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                                        <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"/>
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </ToggleButton.Template>
                                <Grid>
                                    <xtk:ButtonChrome x:Name="ToggleButtonChrome" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="1,0" RenderMouseOver="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=PART_ToggleButton}" RenderPressed="{Binding IsPressed, ElementName=PART_ToggleButton}" RenderChecked="{TemplateBinding IsOpen}" RenderEnabled="{TemplateBinding IsEnabled}">
                                        <Grid x:Name="arrowGlyph" IsHitTestVisible="False" Margin="4,3">
                                            <Path x:Name="Arrow" Data="M0,0L3,0 4.5,1.5 6,0 9,0 4.5,4.5z" Fill="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" Height="5" Margin="0,1,0,0" Width="9"/>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </xtk:ButtonChrome>
                                </Grid>
                            </ToggleButton>
                        </Grid>
                    </xtk:ButtonChrome>
                    <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" HorizontalOffset="1" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=PART_ToggleButton}" Placement="{TemplateBinding DropDownPosition}" VerticalOffset="1"
                                StaysOpen="False">

                        <Border BorderThickness="{DynamicResource DefaultBorderThickness}" Margin="10,0,10,10" Background="{DynamicResource DarkerBaseBrush}" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource PopupBorderBrush}" CornerRadius="{DynamicResource DefaultCornerRadius}">
                            <Grid MinWidth="100" Name="PART_ContentPresenter">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Button x:Name="PART_ButtonWith1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                    1
                                </Button>
                                <Button x:Name="PART_ButtonWith5" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                    5
                                </Button>
                                <Button x:Name="PART_ButtonWith10" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                                    10
                                </Button>
                                <local:CustomIntegerUpDown Grid.Row="3" Value="1"
                                                            Increment="1" ClipValueToMinMax="True"              
                                                            x:Name="MyCustomIntegerUpDown">
                                </local:CustomIntegerUpDown>
                                <Button x:Name="PART_ButtonWithCustom" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Padding="2,2,2,2">
                                    &gt;
                                </Button>
                            </Grid>
                            <Border.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="10" Color="{DynamicResource Base6Color}" />
                            </Border.Effect>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Fill" TargetName="Arrow" Value="#FFAFAFAF"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" TargetName="ActionButtonChrome" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.GrayTextBrushKey}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

In the `OnApplyTemplate` I would expect to be able to access children of templates inside templates inside `this`. But I did not find a way to do this.

Related question of mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56441981/258462).

## Update 1

The starting point of the example, updated (it uses the `TryFindVisualChildElementByName` extension method from BionicCode's answer):

```
internal Popup PartPopup;
internal Button PartButtonWith1, PartButtonWith5, PartButtonWith10, PartButtonWithCustom;
internal RepeatButton IncrementButton;

private void SplitButton_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    PartPopup = (Popup)GetTemplateChild("PART_Popup");
    PartButtonWith1 = (Button)GetTemplateChild("PART_ButtonWith1");
    PartButtonWith5 = (Button)GetTemplateChild("PART_ButtonWith5");
    PartButtonWith10 = (Button)GetTemplateChild("PART_ButtonWith10");
    PartButtonWithCustom = (Button)GetTemplateChild("PART_ButtonWithCustom");

    if (PartPopup != null)
    {
        PartPopup.ApplyTemplateRecursively();

        if (PartPopup.TryFindVisualChildElementByName("PART_IncreaseButton", out FrameworkElement incButton))
        {
            IncrementButton = (RepeatButton)incButton;

            // do something with IncrementButton here
        }

        PartPopup.PreviewMouseDown += PART_Popup_PreviewMouseUp;
        PartPopup.PreviewMouseUp += PART_Popup_PreviewMouseUp;
    }

    if (PartButtonWith1 != null)
    {
        PartButtonWith1.Click += Btns_NewTimer_Click;
    }
    if (PartButtonWith5 != null)
    {
        PartButtonWith5.Click += Btns_NewTimer_Click;
    }
    if (PartButtonWith10 != null)
    {
        PartButtonWith10.Click += Btns_NewTimer_Click;
    }
    if (PartButtonWithCustom != null)
    {
        PartButtonWithCustom.Click += BtnCustom_Click;
    }
}
```

The `ApplyTemplateRecursively` extension method used above, in 2 versions:

### Not working version

Is it possible to make this version work somehow? I think it is more efficient.

```
/// <summary>
/// Not working because the ApplyTemplate affects the VisualTree and when applying
/// templates recursively it does not see the correct updated visual tree to be able
/// to continue.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="root"></param>
internal static void ApplyTemplateRecursively(this System.Windows.DependencyObject root)
{
    if (root is System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup p)
    {
        p.Child.ApplyTemplateRecursively();
        return;
    }

    if (root is FrameworkElement r)
    {
        r.ApplyTemplate();
    }

    foreach (object element in System.Windows.LogicalTreeHelper.GetChildren(root))
    {
        if (element is System.Windows.DependencyObject el)
        {
            ApplyTemplateRecursively(el);
        }
    }
}
```

### Working version

```
/// <summary>
/// I am not sure if this is sufficiently efficient, because it goes through the entire visual tree.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="root"></param>
internal static void ApplyTemplateRecursively(this System.Windows.DependencyObject root)
{
    if (root is System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup p)
    {
        p.Child.ApplyTemplateRecursively();
        return;
    }

    if (root is FrameworkElement r)
    {
        r.ApplyTemplate();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < System.Windows.Media.VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(root); ++i)
    {
        DependencyObject d = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(root, i);
        ApplyTemplateRecursively(d);
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to solve the actual problem.

## Update 2

I have reported [this issue](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/issues/1530).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that the content of a `Popup` is not directly part of the visual tree. That's why looking for visual children of a `Popup` will always return `null`. The content of a `Popup` is rendered separately and is assigned to the `Popup.Child` property. You need to extract those from the `Child` property before continuing tree traversal inside the `Popup`.

The following is a custom visual tree helper method to return the first child element that matches a given name. This helper properly searches inside a `Popup` element. This method is an Extension Method of type `DependencyObject` and has to be put into a `static` `class`:

```
public static bool TryFindVisualChildElementByName(
  this DependencyObject parent,
  string childElementName,
  out FrameworkElement resultElement)
{
  resultElement = null;

  if (parent is Popup popup)
  {
    parent = popup.Child;
    if (parent == null)
    {
      return false;
    }
  }

  for (var childIndex = 0; childIndex < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent); childIndex++)
  {
    DependencyObject childElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, childIndex);        

    if (childElement is FrameworkElement uiElement && uiElement.Name.Equals(
          childElementName,
          StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
      resultElement = uiElement;
      return true;
    }

    if (childElement.TryFindVisualChildElementByName(childElementName, out resultElement))
    {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}
```

It's an Extension Method and it is used like this:

**CustomSplitButton.xaml.cs**

```
// Constructor
public CustomSplitButton()
{
  this.Loaded += GetParts;
}

private void GetParts(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (this.TryFindVisualChildElementByName("PART_Popup", out FrameworkElement popupPart))
  {
    if (popupPart.TryFindVisualChildElementByName("PART_ContentPresenter", out FrameworkElement contentPresenter))
    {
      if (!contentPresenter.IsLoaded)
      {
        contentPresenter.Loaded += CompleteSearch;
      }
      else 
      {
        CompleteSearch(contentPresenter, null);
      }
    }
  }
}

private void CompleteSearch(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{      
  contentPresenter.Loaded -= CompleteSearch;

  if ((sender as DependencyObject).TryFindVisualChildElementByName("PART_IncreaseButton", out FrameworkElement increaseButton))
  {        
    IncrementButton = (RepeatButton) increaseButton;
  }
}
```

**Remarks**

It is very important to search *after* a parent element was `Loaded`.

This is true for all elements in the visual tree. Since the `SplitButton` consists of a drop down that is collapsed by default, not all contents are loaded initially. Once the drop down is opened the `SplitButton` makes its content visible, which will add them to the visual tree. Up to this point the `SplitButton.IsLoaded` property will return `false`, indicating the button's incomplete visual state. What you need to do is, once you encountered a `FrameworkElement` where `FrameworkElement.IsLoaded` returns `false` you have to subscribe to the `FrameworkElement.Loaded` event. In this handler you can continue the visual tree traversal.
`Popup` like elements or collapsed controls add complexity to the visual tree traversal.

---

### Edit: Keep `Popup` open when content was clicked

Now that you have told me that you are using the `SplitButton` inside a `ToolBar` I instantly knew the origin of your problem:

> Classes in WPF which are focus scopes by default are `Window`, `MenuItem`, `ToolBar`, and `ContextMenu`.
>   [Microsoft Docs: [Logical Focus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/focus-overview#logical-focus)]

Simply remove the focus scope from the `ToolBar` to prevent the focus from being removed from the `Popup` as soon as any of its content was clicked (received logical focus):

```
<ToolBar FocusManager.IsFocusScope="False"> 
  <CustomSplitButton />
</ToolBar>
```

---

### Edit: Keep `Popup` open when clicked on *PART_ToggleButton* while the `Popup` is open

To prevent the `Popup` from closing and reopening when the *PART_ToggleButton* is clicked while the `Popup` is open you need to handle the mouse down event (application wide) and the opening of the Popup yourself.

First modify the *PART_Popup* to make it stay open and remove the binding from the `IsOpen` property:

**CustomSplitButton.xaml**

```
<Popup x:Name="PART_Popup"
       IsOpen="False"
       StaysOpen="True"
       AllowsTransparency="True"
       Focusable="False"
       HorizontalOffset="1"
       Placement="{TemplateBinding DropDownPosition}"
       VerticalOffset="1">
```

Then in your `CustomSplitButton` observe the mouse device for mouse down events and determine the hit target. I assume that you retrieved the underlying *PART_Popup* and *PART_ToggleButton* element and stored it in a property named `PartPopup` and `PartToggleButton` (see first part of this answer on how to do it):

**CustomSplitButton.xaml.cs**

```
public CustomSplitButton()
{
  this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
}

private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Mouse.AddPreviewMouseDownHandler(Application.Current.MainWindow, KeepPopupOpen);
}

private void KeepPopupOpen(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
  var mouseClickSourceElement = routedEventArgs.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;
  var isPopupContentClicked = false;
  var isPartToggleButtonClicked = 
    object.ReferenceEquals(routedEventArgs.Source, this) 
      && mouseClickSourceElement.TryFindVisualParentElement(out ButtonBase button) 
      && button.Name.Equals(this.PartToggleButton.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

  if (!isPartToggleButtonClicked)
  {
    isPopupContentClicked = 
      object.ReferenceEquals(routedEventArgs.Source, this) 
        && mouseClickSourceElement.TryFindVisualParentElementByName("PART_ContentPresenter", out FrameworkElement popupContentPresenter));
  }

  this.PartPopup.IsOpen = this.IsOpen = isPartToggleButtonClicked || isPopupContentClicked ;
}
```

**Extension Methods** to find the visual parent by type and by name

```
public static class HelperExtensions
{
  public static bool TryFindVisualParentElement<TParent>(this DependencyObject child, out TParent resultElement)
    where TParent : DependencyObject
  {
    resultElement = null;

    if (child == null)
    {
      return false;
    }

    DependencyObject parentElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

    if (parentElement is TParent parent)
    {
      resultElement = parent;
      return true;
    }

    return parentElement.TryFindVisualParentElement(out resultElement);
  }

  public static bool TryFindVisualParentElementByName(
      this DependencyObject child,
      string elementName,
      out FrameworkElement resultElement)
    {
      resultElement = null;

      if (child == null)
      {
        return false;
      }

      DependencyObject parentElement = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);

      if (parentElement is FrameworkElement frameworkElement &&
          frameworkElement.Name.Equals(elementName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
      {
        resultElement = frameworkElement;
        return true;
      }

      return parentElement.TryFindVisualParentElementByName(elementName, out resultElement);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In both OnApplyTemplate override and a Loaded handler, by debugging I see that in your `TryFindVisualChildElementByName`, `VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent)` tells me that `MyCustomIntegerUpDown` does not have children in the visual tree. How do I make sure the visual tree is loaded? I see that calling ApplyTemplate on a templated element makes your method work well after that for elements found in that template. Thank you.

Comment: I have updated the question with more details. Thank you.

Comment: I have reported [this issue](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/issues/1530). Thank you.

Comment: @silviubogan I updated the answer (the example) to show you the solution. Please read the remarks to understand the issue.

Comment: @silviubogan I've tested your control. When opening the drop down I see three numbered buttons (1, 5 and 10) and a numeric up down. I can click on any of them and the Popup stays open until I click outside of it. I can't reproduce your observed behavior. Do you manipulate the focus or set focus scopes?

Comment: @silviubogan What are your `PartPopup.PreviewMouseUp` and `PartPopup.PreviewMouseDown` handlers doing? When unhooking them does it work (`Popup` stays open)?

Comment: I have reported [this issue](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/issues/1530) on GitHub. There is the markup that reproduces the problem (no code-behind needed). It is related to putting a `<xtk:SplitButton>` inside a ToolBar (not in a ToolBar, it works well). When I have more time, I will analyze the relevant part of the source of Xceed Extended WPF Toolkit and post in that issue. Should I post that here too?

Comment: @silviubogan Ah, the `ToolBar`. As I assumed in my previous comment this is a focus issue. To solve your problem add this attached property to the `ToolBar`: `<ToolBar FocusManager.IsFocusScope="False"> </ToolBar>`. I willl update my answer to address the `ToollBar`. This is a very good example why to provide as much context as possible. Details you think are not important turn out to be the details that make the difference.

Comment: @silviubogan I updated my answer to solve your initial problem.

Comment: I do not know if it is good to put this in the same question, but how can I make the arrow button to just close the Popup when it is open? It currently is closing and reopening the Popup fast.

Comment: @silviubogan I updated my answer to provide a simple solution.